# RaphaelJS color the tip of a path

Tags: svg, raphael

Does anyone know if it's possible to change, say, the last 10 pixels of a path to be a different color? I tried doing it with gradients, and that didn't work. There doesn't seem to be any other way that I can find to do it either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: draw another path on top that's 10 pixels long.

Comment: I thought about that, but wasn't sure how to do it well since I have a ton of different paths in different directions, etc. I guess I could try to pull the BBox from the path and use the coordinates from there to draw another line that's only 10 pixels long.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with Raphael's `element.getSubpath()` interface.

Subpath allows you to get a 'path of a path' between certain points. So, if you have a path already, like

```
var mainPath = paper.path("M10,10R20,70 30,40 40,80 50,10 60,50 70,20 80,30 90,90");
```

You can get a subpath which gives you a 'slice' of that path with arbitrary start and end points:

```
var subpathString = mainpath.getSubpath(20, 50);
```

And then you can create a new element using that path with, say, a different stroke width:

```
var subpath = paper.path(subpathString);
subpath.attr({'stroke-width' : 4});
```

This will then look like this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ndmz3d6/3/

To make the last 10 pixels of your path red, for instance, you just need to know the length of your path. With `element.getTotalLength()`, that's easy:

```
var pathLength = mainPath.getTotalLength();
var subpathStart = pathLength - 10;
var subpathString = mainPath.getSubpath(subpathStart, pathLength);
var highlightedPathSegment = paper.path(subpathString);
highlightedPathSegment.attr({'stroke-width' : 2, stroke : '#FF0000'});
```

And there you should have it: http://jsfiddle.net/1ndmz3d6/5/

Comment: Oh man, that's perfect!! Thank you so much. I didn't even realize that functionality existed.